# What are the various 'kalas' of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama

I have read many times that Lord Rama was born with 14 kalas of Lord Vishnu while Lord Krishna had 16 of the same. I want to ask the following:

1. What exactly are kalas?
2. Are these numbers correct?
3. How many kalas Lord Vishnu have?
4. What are each of these kalas?

Comment: This kind of info is only told by ISkCon followers. There is no such info in scriptures as far as i know. Lord Vishnu or Narayana has infinite auspicious attributes, Kalas to infinite degree. Even brahmavaivarta purana also doesnt say anything like Krishna having 64 kalas and Vishnu 60 kalas. This seems to be pure ISkCoN concept

Comment: @Krishna Thanks for your comment but I don't intend to ask that Lord Krishna has more kalas than Lord Vishnu. I meant that out of lets say 16 or 64 kalas of Lord Vishnu, Lord Rama had some amount of Kalas (may be not full 16 or 64), similarly Lord Krishna had some amount which is similar or less than that of what Lord VIshnu had got. Meaning Lord Vishnu ultimately had full kalas. Now, what are these 16 or 64 kalas? If these are mentioned somewhere then may be people might be comparing the attributes of Lord Vishnu, Lord Rama and Lord Krishna.

Comment: And yes I too agree on Iskcon exaggerating some facts.

Comment: Lord Rama couldnt exhibit all his attributes explicitly as he was on a mission to kill Ravana as a human. But, Raama does exhibit some of his attributes like giving moksha to Jatayu, exhibiting his anger when Ocean didnt answer his prayers etc. Lord Vishnu or Narayana has infinite kalas. No one can count including ISkConites cannot count the infinite number of kalas or attributes. It is sheer dumbness that one tries count the kalas or attributes of Lord whether it is Narayana, Vishnu, Krishna or Raama. I am not sure whether any scripture agrees with the comparison of Kalas.

Comment: @Krishna and Aby --- I study the Gaudiya Vaishnava literature and consequently Iskcon literature as well for 25 years and I can say for sure that these things about 14 kalas and 16 kalas are not Gaudiya Vaishnava idea or concept and it's not Iskcon idea either. From what I have heard about these things is that this idea is expressed in some Shaiva scriptures, but I do not have specific information about this. You can do a simple Google search to find more information about it.

Comment: Lord Vishnu had 16 kalas.Krishna is poorna avataar of supreme lord with16 kalas.while lord rama had 14kalas.lord rama is called poorna avatar according to valmiki ramayan.but tulsidas ramcharit manas mentioned that rama or lord Vishnu is supreme lord.

Answer (score 2):

The abstract concept of *16 Kalas* was used in context of the level of Prana and the phases of the moon. This might give some insights:

> Gurudev, you have talked about *Solah Kalas* (referring to the sixteen
>   extraordinary abilities or Divine qualities). Which are these and what
>   is their importance?
>
> Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: The word *Kala* usually refers to the extent by
>   which the moon waxes (or wanes) in one day. So by this understanding,
>   the Moon possesses 16 different *Kalas* (different phases of the
>   Moon). You can observe this from one *Amavasya* (No-moon day) to the
>   next *Purnima* (Full moon day). So if you count the number of days
>   from one *Amavasya* to the next *Purnima*, it turns out to be 16. And
>   the transition from No-Moon to the Full Moon also symbolizes moving
>   from Zero (nothingness) to Fullness.
>
> On the no-moon day you don’t see the moon at all, and on the full moon
>   day you see the complete moon. This does not mean that the Moon is not
>   there on the day of *Amavasya*. No, it is still there. So by this
>   understanding, these are called the *Solah Kalas*. On the day of solar
>   eclipse, for example, the Moon is there but it cannot be seen, that’s
>   all.
>
> So the word *Kala* is a unit of measure of one’s power, or by what
>   degree one has blossomed or progressed. So, someone may be like a
>   half-moon, someone else may have reached to three quarters of the moon
>   and so on. This was a means of measurement in the ancient days.
>
> In those days, it was said that the life or Prana in a stone is equal
>   to one Kala, the water element is said to have two *Kalas*. Fire has
>   three *Kalas*, *Vayu* (Air element) has four, and the Space or *Akash*
>   has five. Plants and trees are said to have six Kalas. Animals have
>   seven *Kalas*. Human beings have eight *Kalas*.
>
> If it is an extraordinary human being then he is said to have nine
>   *Kalas*. It is said that Lord Parashurama (one of the ten avatars of Lord Vishnu) had nine *Kalas*. They say Lord Rama has 12 *Kalas*. Lord
>   Hanuman is greater than Him in this regard and is said to have 14
>   *Kalas*. That is why he could help Lord Rama. Only a person who is stronger than us can help us.
>
> The Devi (Mother Divine) is called *Shodashakala* (The One with all 16
>   Divine qualities or attributes). It means that she possess all divine
>   and noble qualities, and lacks nothing. Lord Krishna too is said to
>   have all 16 Kalas, which is why He is called as the *Solah Kala
>   sampurna* or the *Purna Avataar*. To have all 16 *Kalas* means to
>   possess all the 16 qualities or signs attributed to the total
>   blossoming and manifestation of Divinity.
>
> If you see the Devi, on one side she is so beautiful and full of love
>   and grace, but on the other side, she is also *Maa Kali* (one of her
>   more terrifying and violent manifestations).
>
> She is graceful and serene, but at the same time she also has a
>   terrifying and violent aspect to Her as. Goddess Durga is very
>   terrifying and awe-inspiring, while Goddess Lakshmi is very calm and
>   graceful.
>
> You can see all the opposite aspects of Divinity coming together in
>   the Devi. The all-bestowing Goddess Lakshmi rides the harmless owl
>   (the mount), and the vanquisher of evil and ignorance, Goddess Durga
>   rides the fierce lion. Just imagine, where would you see both the owl,
>   and the lion!
>
> In the same way Lord Krishna is also said to have possessed all the
>   *Solah Kalas*. Why is this so? In Lord Krishna, you see the complete and total manifestation of Divinity in every way. He is so complete.
>   He is the King of thieves. He does not steal small things, he steals
>   away your very mind. That is why He is called as *Chita-Chora* (the
>   beautiful One who completely captures and steals away the mind).
>
> He is also called as *Ranchhodrai* (meaning the cowardly one who flees
>   the battlefield) in Gujarat. They say that He ran away from the
>   battlefield in the middle of the war. But on the other side He lifted
>   up the *Sudarshan Chakra* (the Lord’s divine discus) to defeat
>   *Bhishma Pitamaha* (the grandsire of the Pandavas and the Kauravas in the Mahabharata) . So He is very brave and valiant too.
>
> So, on one side he is very brave and on the other side he is like a
>   coward. One cannot even imagine how complete he is. He is obedient as
>   well, but He is also the one who breaks the rules.
>
> In the *Bhagawat*, it is mentioned at many places that Lord Krishna is
>   perfect and complete in every possible aspect. That is why it is said
>   that one should not emulate Lord Krishna (Laughter). Follow the path
>   of Lord Rama and listen to Lord Krishna. Don’t walk in the way that
>   Lord Krishna did. If you go and steal the clothes of a lady, you will
>   be in big trouble (jokingly referring to one of the pastimes of the
>   Lord where He steals the clothes of some ladies bathing in the river
>   and hides them on a tree).

http://www.artofliving.org/wisdom-q-a-25-february-2014-qa-5