# Were all human avataras of God Kshatriya or Brahmin?

Tags: avatars, caste-system

The animal avataras like fish,tortoise wouldn't have caste - but how about the human avataras?

Comment: Something related I had found - In Lalitavistara Sutra, Gautama Buddha said  “The Bodhisattvas appear only in two kinds of lineage, the one of the brahmanas and of the warriors (kshatriya)."... Next Buddha (Maitreya) as told by Buddhist scriptures will be a Brahmin.

Comment: @Mr. Sigma the theosophists seem to have similar theories.

Comment: Do you mean only avatars of Vishnu or other Devas too?

Comment: Q3 in my Q [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/how-do-the-scriptures-describe-some-of-the-key-features-of-avataras) is the same .. @SK

Comment: @rickross -  your question is if there is such a requirement.  Mine is if thats what actually happened (rules are meant to be broken and so forth)..

Comment: @the destroyer - all Gods, Devas and so forth.

Comment: Okay I hv not close voted though just shared something closely related @SK

Answer (score 3):

Well, Vidura who is considered to be a Shudra, is considered an incarnation of Yama:

> And there was a Rishi of the name of Animandavya of great fame. And he was conversant with the interpretations of the Vedas, was illustrious, gifted with great energy, and of great reputation. And, accused of theft, though innocent, the old Rishi was impaled. He thereupon summoned Dharma (Yama) and told him these words, 'In my childhood I had pierced a little fly on a blade of grass, O Dharma! I recollect that one sin: but I cannot call to mind any other. I have, however, since practised penances a thousandfold. Hath not that one sin been conquered by this my asceticism? And because the killing of a Brahmana is more heinous than that of any other living thing, therefore, hast thou, O Dharma, been sinful. **Thou shalt, therefore, be born on earth in the Sudra order.' And for that curse Dharma was born a Sudra in the form of the learned Vidura of pure body who was perfectly sinless.** (**Mahabharata, Adi Parva, Section LXIII**)

Comment: Probably the OP meant incarnations of Vishnu. I wonder whether Krishna was a pure kshatriya.

Comment: @LazyLubber No, check the comment section above. He clearly specifies that he meant for all Devas.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "I wonder whether Krishna was a pure kshatriya"- why?